# Encryption using Wavelet transform

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science, fourier-transform, cryptography, wavelets

I need to know about an article, book or other reference that deals with encryption using Fourier transform and the Wavelet.
(I plan to use *matlab* or other recommended software.)

Comment: Do you mean the number theoretic transform ? (replacing $e^{2i \pi nk/N}$ by $w^{nk}$ where $w^N = 1$ in the finite field $\mathbf{F}_q, q \equiv 1 \bmod N$) Overwise the DFT exchanges convolution and multiplication which is useful to compute the multiplication and exponentiation of polynomials (also integers in base $b$ are some sort of polynomials in $b$)

Comment: I don't see how you could encrypt something with wavelets. The forward and inverse transform have the same computational complexity. Encryption generally requires a fast forward transform and an exponential time inverse transform.